# How to show a file extension within a document library view

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm working on a Custom webpart and would like to show icons for the extensions.
This is on a Sharepoint Designer 2010.
Also if i have extensions like .wav how can i show or add a custome icon.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change File association icons globally by following steps described here:

[Changing File Associations Icons in SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/02/17/changing-file-associations-icons-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Basic steps are:

1. Upload icon file to SP (`\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES`)
2. Locate `DocIcon.xml` (`\14\TEMPLATE\XML`)
3. Add  `<Mapping Key=”[YOUR EXTENSION]” Value=”[ICON FILE]”/>` (eg. `<Mapping Key=”pdf” Value=”icpdf.gif”/>`)
4. Make `iisreset`

Answer (score 5):

If it's custom code then you can use [SPUtility.MapToIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.maptoicon.aspx) to get the name of the icon in "/_layouts/images/"

If it's a view then just add the column DocIcon

For adding new images see the answer by @Vedran

Comment: Thanks guys I was after showing the icons in a custom webpart.
Using the ddwrt funstion worked.